# How do applications read assemblies and visualize .NET forms?

Tags: .net, winforms

Applications like Passolo, Alchemy Catalyst and Lingobit Localizer can read DLLs and visualize .NET controls, such as windows, forms, and dialogs. How might something like this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with those specific applicatios--but they likely use .NET's Reflection metadata.

An assembly can be loaded (or loaded specifically for reflection) and then all Types within that assembly can be inspected.  That inspection could consist of finding types which inherit from a WinForms `Control`, or perhaps which inherit from something defined in `System.Windows.Forms`.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine the basic idea is to search the dlls via reflection for classes derived from Form or UserControl and instantiate them.  Then render the result on your own surface.